# Extracting multiple phone number types using regex

Tags: python, regex

My current code finds all cases where '+44' shows up in a website. I want this code to also produce all cases where '0131' occurs. Any help is appreciated, thank you. Code attached below.

```
phones = re.findall(r'\+44', page.decode())
phones.sort()
print (f'\n [+] {len(phones)} PHONE NUMBERS FOUND:\n')
for phone in phones:
print(phone)
```

Comment: you can use the following regex:r' \+44|0131' instead of your current

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: @Did you run you code on Python 3.6?

Comment: Yeah, im using Python 3.6

Comment: @Joe Bloggs next time try to read some material before asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will help you to find numbers of length 10:

```
import re
re.findall(r"\+44\s+?\d{10}|0131\s+?\d{10}", "This is number  +44 1234567890 and 0131 9090909090323")
```